# Sort ObservableCollection with your own sorting algorithm using Task Parallel Library

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox, task-parallel-library, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection binded with Listbox. I don't want to use CollectionView sorting. I want to use Merge Sort algorithm using TPL. I know I can use ListCollectionView and I have an option for CustomSort and put there new Sort(). I have a problem how to implement it correctly with Task Parallel Library?

Comment: I have implemented merge sort - I have a class model that supports IComparable and implements CompareTo method.I sort ObservableCollection that makes use of the custom LINQ extension. That's my new class Sort with method MergeSort with (this Ilist obj) as a parameter. The expression performs a merge sort with the assumption that the items in the generic collection support IComparable. And for example i have ObservableCollection _person, I just call _person.MergeSort(). I don't know how to use it with Tasks. @svick

Comment: I think the problem is that CollectionView does not support that. Maybe using a Dispatcher.Invoke?

Answer (score 0):

If you need better performance to sort the list, I would advise you to sort it before making it an observable collection.

ObservableCollection is raising events when you change it and that will impact performance badly.It will also make your UI update at each step of the sort, and you don't want this I assume.

I think you are better off sorting it as a list and rebinding whatever UI element to it later. 
this probably depends on the size of the list, and the performance you are looking for.